# One graph from many metrics in one query

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-variable

I have a large number of custom metrics like:

```
Request_GetData_XXXX_duration_seconds_sum
Request_GetData_XXXX_duration_seconds_count
Request_GetData_YYYY_duration_seconds_sum
Request_GetData_YYYY_duration_seconds_count
```

Their number and names (XXXX and YYYY) may change, but they are always paired and end in `_sum` and `_count.`
In Grafana, I draw an Average plot in the following way:

```
sum by (container) (
  rate(Request_GetData_XXXX_duration_seconds_sum{}[5m]) / 
  rate(Request_GetData_XXXX_duration_seconds_count{}[5m]) )
```

Everything works.

I made a drop down menu and through a variable
`{name=~"Request_GetData_.*_seconds_count$"}`
And Regex `/(.+)_count{/` get a list of metrics

result:

- Request_GetData_XXXX_duration_seconds
- Request_GetData_YYYY_duration_seconds

And in Grafana I write in the request:

```
sum by (container) (rate(${myVar_metrics}_sum{}[5m]) / rate(${myVar_metrics}_count{}[5m]))
```

Everything is working. But I need the following. I need one graph on which there will be all the metrics `Request_GetData_XXXX_duration_seconds`, `Request_GetData_YYYY_duration_seconds` and etc.

Tell me how can this be done? The Multi-value and Include All option options on a variable break such a graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, consider converting you metrics to the [best practices](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/naming/#labels) of Prometheus. I anticipate something like this:

```
mysystem_request_duration_seconds_sum{type="XXXX"}
mysystem_request_duration_seconds_count{type="XXXX"}
mysystem_request_duration_seconds_sum{type="YYYY"}
mysystem_request_duration_seconds_count{type="YYYY"}
```

This way you wouldn't need all this hustle with metric names.

In this case your query would look like this:

```
sum by (container) (
rate(mysystem_request_duration_seconds_sum{type="$myVar"}[5m]) / 
rate(mysystem_request_duration_seconds_count{type="$myVar"}[5m]) )
```

---

For your current situation you'll need to employ a couple of tricks:

1. Since you can't query multiple metrics by name with regex, you'll need to use `{__name__=~"${myVar_metrics}_sum"}`.
2. To divide metrics, you need them to have matching labels.
   You can add label to metric based on metrics name using `label_replace`:

```
label_replace({__name__=~"${myVar_metrics}_sum"} ,"foo", "$1", "__name__", "(${myVar_metrics})_sum")
```

3. Range selector can be applied only to a metric selector. Since `label_replace` is a function and not a metric selector, you'll need to use [subquery](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#subquery) syntax. Basically, the difference is addition of semicolon into range selector:

```
rate(label_replace({__name__=~"${myVar_metrics}_sum"} ,"foo", "$1", "__name__", "(${myVar_metrics})_sum")[5m : ])
```

Resulting query would look like this:

```
sum by (container) (
 rate(
  label_replace(
   {__name__=~"${myVar_metrics}_sum"} ,
   "foo", "$1",
   "__name__", "(${myVar_metrics})_sum")
  [5m : ])
/rate(
  label_replace(
   {__name__=~"${myVar_metrics}_count"} ,
   "foo", "$1", 
   "__name__", "(${myVar_metrics})_count")
  [5m : ])
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your advice helped!
Regarding the best practices of Prometheus, you are right. I will contact the developers to correct the metrics. Once again THANK YOU SO MUCH!